# How to use /CLR setting in OPENCV program in MS VC++ 2015

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, clr

I am using Visual studio 2015/ c++ / OpenCV /

where I a have to use the System.dll header file inside an openCV project

```
#include< System.dll >
```

In order to use this header file I have to change to Common Language Runtime Support (/clr), but that is causing a linker error

> Error
>   LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1900' in Source.obj \OpenCV Red object detection\opencv_ts300d.lib(opencv_ts_pch.obj)

Could you please help me resolve this error?

To my understating /clr in not supporting OpenCV lib and header files ?

More info: I have the runtime library: Multi-Threaded Debug DLL(/MDd) chosen.
My motive behind using System.dll is I have few other program with multithread which requires this.

Comment: ***LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1900' in Source.obj*** Looks like you are mixing compiler versions. Make sure your Opencv binaries were compiled for the compiler you are using.

Comment: This is want i tried I noticed that openCV did not have VC15 version inside build but i was using visual studio 2015, So i built my own library for vc2015 by downloading the master openCV file from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv and following this tutorial https://youtu.be/HQP-Gl1J25s

Comment: You are looking for a vc14 folder (if there is one). Visual Studio 2015 is vc14.